# select with multiple where and count

Tags: sql, sql-server

The following query returns what is needed but I need to modify it so I can 
only select the records from documents in which the number of `DocID` is greater than 3 along with what is in the where clause.  When attempting to do so I always get the error:

> An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a
>   subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column
>   being aggregated is an outer reference.

How would I write the query to satisfy the count of `DocID` being greater than 3?  `DocID` is the PK of the documents table.

```
use newCityCollection
select a.CaseNumberKey, a.SearchUserID, c.DocType, c.RelatedDocID
from documents c
JOIN   newCityCollection.dbo.PropertyInformation a ON C.CaseNumberKey = A.CaseNumberKey
where  c.DocType = 'Assignment' and c.RelatedDocID is null and a.ClientKey = 3 and (count(c.docID) > 3)
```

Comment: Add your tables schema so we can understand where the DocID come from. Also which rdbms are you using? Is it SQLServer?

Comment: Can you show us your query with `COUNT` function?

Comment: What do you mean by schema?  It is dbo and is autoincrement integer.

Comment: There is only one `DocID` in each record of the `documents` table. You need to specify where you would find these three or more `DocID` values, i.e. group the query or use a subquery to count related records. You haven't explained in the question where to look for the related `DocID` values.

Comment: Do you want to get result if you have more than 3 record in table `Documents` or if you have values in `DocID` more than 3?

Comment: What I am trying to find is records in the master table (PropertyInformation) in which there are 3 or more Document.DocID and Document.DocType = 'Assignment' and Document.RelatedDocID is null.

Comment: Have you tried removing the `(count(c.docID) > 3)` from the WHERE clause and added the `HAVING` clause? (ex: `HAVING count(c.docID) > 3`).

Comment: If I use having I still get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the last part of your WHERE clause and add a having clause:

```
  USE newCityCollection
SELECT a.CaseNumberKey, a.SearchUserID, c.DocType, c.RelatedDocID
FROM documents c
JOIN   newCityCollection.dbo.PropertyInformation a ON C.CaseNumberKey = A.CaseNumberKey
WHERE c.DocType = 'Assignment' and c.RelatedDocID is null and a.ClientKey = 3
GROUP BY a.CaseNumberKey, a.SearchUserID, c.DocType, c.RelatedDocID
HAVING count(c.docID) > 3
```